# Possible Misuse of Polymorphic Association of Model in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, polymorphic-associations

In my app I have three models of interest. The first is the Patient model, which has_many Record models. Similarly the Record model has_many Diagnosis models. Initially I had the Patient model accessing the diagnoses via:

```
:has_many :diagnoses, :through => :records
```

However the problem I had with this was that **I also want the Patient model to be able to create a Diagnosis object independent of the Record model**. For instance during an admission the patient might be diagnosed with a new condition. However she might also have a history of having a condition (a prior diagnosis) and so I would like to keep track of that without having to resort to creating a new model.

I tried using polymorphic associations as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), such that my models look like:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :records
  has_many :diagnoses, :as => :medical_history
  # ...
end

class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  has_many :diagnoses, :as => :medical_history
  # ...
end

class Diagnosis < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :medical_history, :polymorphic => true
  # ...
end
```

The problem I'm having is that while I can successfully create Diagnosis objects via the Record object, when I call `p.diagnoses` (where `p` is a Patient object) it doesn't give me access to all the Diagnosis objects like I expect it to.

*To reiterate, what I want is to be able to create a Diagnosis object either through the Record model or through the Patient model, but be able to have the Patient model access all Diagnosis objects that were either created through itself or via the Record model (which should be possible since the Record model belongs to the Patient model).*

I'm pretty sure this is me not really understanding how polymorphic associations work and I could be totally misusing polymorphic associations as well. So I appreciate all the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your use of polymorphism is appropriate.

The Diagnoses created through Record (a confusing term in this context, since it can mean patient record or database record) will not automatically be added to Patient. You need to do one of two things:

1. Using a callback (e.g., after_save) on your Record model, add all Diagnoses to Record.patient and call Record.patient.save. Note, your Patient may also have callbacks, so be careful they don't call each other.
2. Add a method in Patient to combine p.diagnoses with p.records.diagnoses when needed. As in (code untested):

   ```
   def diagnoses_all
     // you could memoize this if so inclined
     (diagnoses + records.collect{|r| r.diagnoses}.flatten).uniq
   end
   ```

In either case, you can always call Patient.records.diagnoses, so that knowledge is not lost. However, in the first case, if you want to know which diagnoses were create through Patient, you'd have to write another method to basically invert diagnoses_all, i.e., subtract Patient.records.diagnoses from Patient.diagnoses.

To get a better understanding of what's happening, take a look at the (assuming SQL) schema that was generated for the 3 tables. In the console, instantiate a Patient, call p.diagnoses and p.records.diagnoses, watch the logs for the generated SQL.

Comment: Thanks pduey, I had gotten this to work using something similar to your second option - it's just nice knowing that I'm not completely off the mark with my use of polymorphic associations (although if anyone disagrees I am happy to hear why).